# PHP Private Variable issue

Tags: php, oop, private

I try to get value of a private variable (limit), but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in     /home/vagrant/Code/wp/wp-content/plugins/StorePress/app/library/Pagination.php on line 36

My Class:

```
class Pagination
  {
   private $limit = 0;
   private $limit_start = 0;
   private $total = 0;

 /**
  * Generate Pagination for Products
  * @param $pagination
  * @return string
  */
public function __constructor($pagination = null)
{
    $this->limit = $pagination['limit'];
    $this->lim_start = ($pagination['start']) ?: null;
    $this->total = $pagination['total'];
}

public function generatePagination()
{
   echo $this->limit;
}
```

Here, I'm trying to print "$this->limit", a private variable, but it's not allowed to print the value that are assigned by the "__constructor".

Is there anything wrong in my code or is there any other solution to get that value?

Answer (score 3):

I think, that the problem is in your OOP construction. You cannot echo `$this` private variable, when you don't create class object as first. So the solution might be:

```
class Pagination
  {
   private $limit = 0;
   private $limit_start = 0;
   private $total = 0;

 /**
  * Generate Pagination for Products
  * @param $pagination
  * @return string
  */
public function __constructor($pagination = null)
{
    $this->limit = $pagination['limit'];
    $this->lim_start = ($pagination['start']) ?: null;
    $this->total = $pagination['total'];
}

public function generatePagination()
{
   return $this->limit;
}
```

and then in your code, where you need to echo the limit value, you can use:

```
$pagination = new Pagination();
echo $pagination->generatePagination();
```

At first line, you will create new Pagination() object and in the second line, you will return the $limit value from your generatePagination class function.

Comment: $pagination = Pagination::getPagination();

This also returns the same error.

Comment: Yes, of course, because the double colon operator, is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class. Your class is not static and `$limit` variable is not constant, so you can't use this construction. [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: Then what is the solution to access private variable from different functions while call from controller with its object ?

Comment: The best solution is the create new function in your class Pagination, which will return only the `$limit` variable - `generatePagination()` in my code do this. Then you need to create a new instance of your class Pagination and then you can get `$limit` value via `->generatePagination()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your keyword __constructor be __construct instead according to this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)